# Calculating the integral $\int \frac{14x+1}{2-7x-4x^2} \, dx$

Tags: calculus

We have the following integral

$$
\int \frac{14x+1}{2-7x-4x^2} \, dx
$$

By factoring the denominator we get

$$
-\int \frac{14x+1}{4x^2+7x-2} \, dx = -\int \frac{14x+1}{(4x-1)(x+2)} \, dx
$$

And breaking into partial fractions

$$
-\int \frac{2}{4x-1} + \frac{3}{x+2} \, dx = -\int \frac{2}{4x-1} \, dx - \int \frac{3}{x+2} \, dx = - 2\int \frac{1}{4x-1} \, dx - 3 \int \frac{1}{x+2} \, dx
$$

Then by substituting (and resubstituting) we get

$$
- 2\int \frac{1}{4u} \, du - 3 \int \frac{1}{v} \, dv = -\frac{2}{4} \ln(u)-3 \ln (v)=-\frac{1}{2}\ln(4x-1)-3\ln (x+2)
$$

However, the expected result is
$$
-\frac{1}{2}\ln(1-4x)-3\ln (x+2)
$$

Have I made a mistake somewhere? If so, where?

Comment: You can check your answer by taking its derivative. Don't forget your constant of integration.

Comment: It isn't $\int\frac{1}{y}\text{d}y=\log y+c$, it is $\int\frac{1}{y}\text{d}y=\log|y|+c$.

Comment: `Integrate[(14 x + 1)/(2 - 7 x - 4 x^2), x]`  $-3 \log (x+2)-\frac{1}{2} \log (1-4 x)$

Comment: @Bernkastel see below for an expanded version of your comment

Comment: There are three intervals to be considered $(-\infty, -2),$ $(-2,{1\over 4})$ and $({1\over 4},\infty).$  Your solution is correct for $x>{1\over 4}.$ The solution given in the answer is valid for $(-2,{1\over 4}).$ One has to be careful with adding a constant because the general solution is defined on three disjoint intervals and we can apply different constant on each of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Too long for a comment:

@Bernkastel is absolutely (haha) right. Your solution $+c$ is valid on a certain (open) portion of the real line, and the advertised solution on an other.  With absolute values thrown in, one gets the largest domain for a solution over the reals.

To be more explicit: on the half-line $x<0$, $ |x| = -x$. So, calculating the derivative on that interval, one gets (by the chain rule)
$$ \left(\ln |x|\right)' = \left(\ln \left(-x\right) \right)' = {1\over -x} \cdot (-1) = {1\over x};$$
similarly on the half-line $x>0$.

Answer (score 0):

Both results are correct because it's an indefinite integral.
The difference between the 2 results is just an imaginary constant (constant of integration): $$\frac{i \pi }{2}$$